# Creating an onclick button based on a onkeyup textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea with an onclick funtion to regist a comment, and yesterday I realized that mobile users can't comment because they don't they na "Enter" key on their cellphones keyboard, so I was trying to create a button so mobile users can post comments too. But here's my problema, I tried to copy the onkeyup code already placed on the textarea which it is by default and change the onkeyup to onclick. The thing is my new button I'm trying to create doesn't work

Here's the default code for comment posts with the Enter button:

```
<textarea class="auto-grow-input" name="text" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['comment_textarea_label']; ?>" data-placeholder="<?php echo $lang['comment_textarea_label']; ?>" data-height="24" onkeyup="SK_registerComment(this.value,<?php echo $sk['input']['post']['id']; ?>,<?php echo $sk['input']['timeline']['id']; ?>,event);">
    <?php echo $lang['comment_textarea_label']; ?>
</textarea>
```

and here's the button I'm trying to create:

```
<button class="commentButton" onClick="SK_registerComment(this.value,<?php echo $sk['input']['post']['id']; ?>,<?php echo $sk['input']['timeline']['id']; ?>,event);">
    <?php echo $lang['comment_button']; ?>
</button>
```

**==== Update ====**

Here's the `SK_registerComment` function

```
// Post comment
function SK_registerComment(text, post_id, timeline_id, event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey == 0) {
        main_wrapper = $('.story_' + post_id);
        comment_textarea = main_wrapper.find('.comment-textarea');
        textarea_wrapper = comment_textarea.find('textarea');
        textarea_wrapper.val('');

        SK_progressIconLoader(comment_textarea);

        $.post(SK_source() + '?t=post&a=comment&post_id=' + post_id, {text: text, timeline_id: timeline_id}, function (data) {

            if (data.status == 200) {
                main_wrapper.find('.comment-wrapper:last').before(data.html);
                main_wrapper.find('.story-comment-activity').html(data.activity_html);
            }

            SK_progressIconLoader(comment_textarea);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: add your SK_registerComment function

Comment: `this.value` on the button is not the same as `this.value` on the textarea. You need to grab the textarea's value instead

Answer (score 0):

`this.value` will be the button's value, not the textarea's. Try to use `document.getElementsByName("text")[0].innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 0):

best way is remove this.value from params and directly take value inside function using document.getElementsByName('text')[0].value

```
 <button class="commentButton" onClick="SK_registerComment(<?php echo $sk['input']['post']['id']; ?>,<?php echo $sk['input']['timeline']['id']; ?>,event);">
<?php echo $lang['comment_button']; ?>
</button>

function SK_registerComment(postid,timelineid,event){
   value = document.getElementsByName('text')[0].value;
   // rest of your code here
}

function SK_registerComment(post_id, timeline_id, event) {

  text = document.getElementsByName('text')[0].value;   // using jquery $('textarea[name="text"]').val();
  alert(text);
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey == 0) {
    main_wrapper = $('.story_' + post_id);
    comment_textarea = main_wrapper.find('.comment-textarea');
    textarea_wrapper = comment_textarea.find('textarea');
    textarea_wrapper.val('');

    SK_progressIconLoader(comment_textarea);

    $.post(SK_source() + '?t=post&a=comment&post_id=' + post_id, {text: text, timeline_id: timeline_id}, function (data) {

        if (data.status == 200) {
            main_wrapper.find('.comment-wrapper:last').before(data.html);
            main_wrapper.find('.story-comment-activity').html(data.activity_html);
        }

        SK_progressIconLoader(comment_textarea);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it's still not working. I even tried to exhchange `"text"` for `'text'` because it wasn't let me close the button tag and still nothing

Comment: then best way is remove this.value from params and  directly take value inside function using document.getElementsByName('text')[0].value

Comment: @JackDavis can you please add SK_registerComment in question ?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to find, but it's a long file where I think this part of code must be. it may took a while

Comment: I've found the fuction, check out my edit to the answer

Comment: @JackDavis check my updated answer. have apply changes in function. have add alert(text). so you can check that you are able to get text or not

Comment: I tried this exactly and still nothing man :S The alert pops up everytime I do click on a key or click on it, but the comment doesn't appear. shouldn't this be working if I added just this `class="auto-grow-input commentButton" name="text"` for the button?

Comment: @JackDavis you dont need to add  name="text" to the button remove that also remove auto-grow-input then check  name="text" only for that text area not for other inputs .. make sure name="text" is only for text area in whole page